# jquery form validate not working+cannot add user to db

Tags: php, jquery

I've spent lots of time on this and still cannot make it work.

This is how registration.php looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_reg").validate({
            rules:{
                "reg_login":{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:4,
                    maxlength:15,
                    remote:{
                        type:"post",
                        url:"/reg/check_login.php"
                    }
                },
                "reg_pass":{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:4,
                    maxlength:15
                }
            },
            messages:{
                "reg_login":{
                    required:"Enter login!",
                    minlength:"From 4 to 15 symbols!",
                    maxlength:"From 4 to 15 symbols!",
                    remote:"Login is already in use!"
                },
                "reg_pass":{
                    required:"Enter password!",
                    minlength:"From 4 to 15 symbols!",
                    maxlength:"From 4 to 15 symbols!"
                }
            },
        submitHandler:function(form){
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success:function(data){
                    if (data == 'true'){
                        $("#block-form-reg").fadeOut(300, function(){
                            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("You have been registered!");
                            $("#form_submit").hide();
                        )};
                    }else{
                        $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is handler_reg.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("../include/db_connect.php");
include_once("../functions/functions.php");

$error = array();
    $login = strtolower(clear_string($_POST["reg_login"]));
    $pass = strtolower(clear_string($_POST["reg_pass"]));

    if(strlen($login) < 4 or strlen($login) > 15){
        $error[] = "Login must contain from 4 to 15 symbols";
    }else{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM reg WHERE login = '$login'", $link);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $error[] = "Login is already in use!";
        }
    }
    if(strlen($pass) < 4 or  trlen($pass) > 15) {$error[] = "Password must contain from 4 to 15 symbols";}
    if(count($error)){
        echo implode('<br/>',$error);
    }else{
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $pass = strrev($pass);
        $pass = "9nm2rv".$pass."2yo6z";

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO reg_user(login, pass)
            VALUES(
                '".$login."',
                '".$pass."'
            )", $link);
        echo 'true';
    }
?>
```

And the last one - check_login.php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    include_once("../include/db_connect.php");
    include_once("../functions/functions.php");

    $login = clear_string($_POST["reg_login"]);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM reg WHERE login='$login'", $link);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
}
?>
```

I've created a user in db with login:admin and pass:admin. When I press submit with login:admin and pass:user it tells me

```
Notice: Undefined index: reg_pass in /home/students/babae3ap/website/reg/handler_reg.php on line 9
Password must contain from 4 to 15 symbols.
```

And when I make login:user and pass:admin -

```
Notice: Undefined index: reg_pass in /home/students/babae3ap/website/reg/handler_reg.php on line 9
Login is already in use!
Password must contain from 4 to 15 symbols
```

Did anyone face this kind of problem?

Comment: plus jquery doesn't appear on main page if I leave the inputs clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spell mistake in code:

```
 if(strlen($pass) < 4 or  trlen($pass) > 15) {$error[] = "Password must contain from 4 to 1
```

to

```
 if(strlen($pass) < 4 or  strlen($pass) > 15) {$error[] = "Password must contain from 4 to 1
```

Comment: nothing changes anyway, I'm having the same problem

Comment: You are getting a Notice there : **Notice: Undefined index: reg_pass ** Check the name and id you have used in the html form for password field

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still jquery doesn't work and doesn't redirect me to the registration.php